# How can I measure that my web application has been fully undeployed in a container?

Tags: java, tomcat, weblogic

I have experienced some nasty dangling daemonized threads which kept the class loader hanging which eventually causes perm gen exhaustion.

Who knows what other kinds of nasties there are!

How can I be sure via evidence that my web application has been fully undeployed in a web container?

Answer (score 1):

You can check in the manager application, or via JMX. If the context is not listed, it should be undeployed.

Btw, also watch the log files for errors and warnings during undeployment.

Comment: In weblogic where should i be looking? Because when i deployed a nasty app in tomcat it warned me of a daemonized thread but i have not seen that warning when using weblogic.

Comment: From my understanding, Tomcat7 is one of the fiew that will really warn about. Other just don't warn.

Comment: Yea Tomcat is pretty aggressive when it comes to undeploying web apps, most of the others don't go as far as Tomcat does.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your deployment setup, you can check under /server//tmp/_WL_user directory as well.